# The term 'xxd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function

Tags: react-native, keytool

I am trying to create a hash key for my Android APP (SMS retriever API ), i follow this link

https://medium.com/@rodrigohsb/automatic-sms-authentication-without-asking-permission-sms-retriever-api-47eb5026b9a3

but while running key tool command i am getting following error :

> xxd : The term 'xxd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
>   spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At line:1 char:57"

Answer (score 3):

[`xxd`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-xxd/) is a linux command to make a hexdump or do the reverse, sometimes shipped with `vim`.

Depending on your OS, try to install `xxd` or `vim` and it may fix this problem.